# If $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, prove that every $\Omega$-subgroup [of $G$ has] a composition series.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

This is part of **Exercise 3.1.4** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5COmega%24%2C%20Composition%20series%20&p=10), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

On page 28, *ibid.*,

> A *right operator group* is a triple $(G, \Omega, \alpha)$ consisting of a group $G$, a set $\Omega$ called the *operator domain* and a function $\alpha:G\times \Omega\to G$ such that $g\mapsto (g,\omega)\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $G$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. We shall write $g^\omega$ for $(g,\omega)\alpha$ and speak of the *$\Omega$-group* if the function $\alpha$ is understood.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $G$ is an $\Omega$-group, an *$\Omega$-subgroup* of $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is *$\Omega$-admissible*, that is, such that $h^\omega\in H$ whenever $h\in H$ and $\omega\in\Omega$.

On page 63, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be an operator group with operator domain $\Omega$. An $\Omega$-series (of finite length) in $G$ is a finite sequence of $\Omega$-subgroups including $1$ and $G$ such that each member of the sequence is a normal subgroup of its successor: thus a series can be written
>
> $$1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\dots\lhd G_l=G.$$
>
> The [. . .] quotient groups $G_{i+1}/G_i$ are the *factors* of the series.

On page 64, *ibid.*,

> If $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{T}$  are $\Omega$-series of [an $\Omega$-group] $G$, call $\mathbf{S}$ a *refinement* of $\mathbf{T}$ if every term of $\mathbf{T}$ is also a term of $\mathbf{S}$. If there is at least one term of $\mathbf{S}$ which is not a term of $\mathbf{T}$, then $\mathbf{S}$ is a *proper refinement* of $\mathbf{T}$.

On page 65, *ibid.*,

> An $\Omega$-series which has no proper refinements is called an *$\Omega$-composition series*.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $\Omega$ is empty, we speak of a *composition series*.

### The Question:

> If $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, prove that every $\Omega$-subgroup [of $G$ has] a composition series.

### Thoughts:

I'm somewhat confused: if $H$ is an $\Omega$-subgroup of $G$, then, in particular, it is a group, so . . .

Yeah, I think that some refinement of

$$1\lhd H$$

would be a composition series of $H$, which would, I suppose, be guaranteed to exist since $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, itself a refinement of

$$1\lhd_\Omega G,$$

where $\lhd_\Omega$ means "is a normal $\Omega$-subgroup of".

I don't think I am expressing my thoughts clearly enough. For lack of a better term, perhaps there is some "forgetful functor" to go from $\lhd_\Omega$ to $\lhd$.

I don't know . . .

---

I first encountered $\Omega$-groups in Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*, page 274, a few months ago. They made sense then.

Here is my previous question:

- [Abelian and nonabelian groups with the same composition factors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138096/104041)

---

Working through an example might help.

Consider $\Omega=\{x\}$, $G=S_3$, and

$$\begin{align}
\alpha:S_3\times \Omega &\to S_3\\
(\sigma,x)&\mapsto \sigma.
\end{align}$$

The series

$$1\lhd_\Omega \Bbb Z_3\lhd_\Omega S_3$$

is an $\Omega$-composition series by inspection.

The subgroup $H=(\{e, (123), (321)\}, \circ)$ is an $\Omega$-subgroup, since $\tau^x=\tau\in H$ for all $\tau\in H$.

Perhaps this example is not particularly illustrative, because $H$ so clearly has the composition series

$$1\lhd H$$

without recourse to $G$ and its $\Omega$-composition series.

---

Please help :)

Comment: But $H\cong\mathbb Z_3$.  Did you try taking intersections of the subgroups in the composition series of the super $\Omega $-group  $G $ with $H $?

Comment: Okay, @ChrisCuster. I haven't tried that yet. I'm not sure what it would achieve. Besides, I'm more concerned with doing the titular exercise.

Comment: Okay, but that's what I was trying to focus on.  Say we have $1=G_0\triangleright G_1\triangleright G_2\dots\triangleright G_l=G$.  What can we say about $1=G_0\cap H\triangleright G_1\cap H\triangleright\dots\triangleright G_l\cap H=H$?

Comment: I see, @ChrisCuster; thank you. I'll think about it some more in several hours time as I need sleep. Also, your triangles are facing the wrong way!

Comment: Nice catch.  Figures.

Comment: Don't you want to say that a composition series is one with no _proper_ refinement?

Comment: Yes, thank you, @ChrisCuster :)

Comment: I have a rough idea of what to do here, @ChrisCuster, but would you mind typing up an answer for me, please? My thoughts are that $$1=1\cap H\lhd G_1\cap H\lhd \dots \lhd G_l\cap H=G\cap H=H$$ is the composition series for $H$ but I'm not sure how to show that yet.

Comment: In general, it need not be a composition/$\Omega$-composition series for $H$, as the example of a finite simple group and a proper non-simple nontrivial group shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use Theorem 3.1.5:

> **3.1.5** An $\Omega$-group $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series if and only if it satisfies max-$\Omega$s and min-$\Omega$s.

In other words, if it satisfies ACC and DCC on $\Omega$-subgroups.

If $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, then it satisfies ACC and DCC on $\Omega$-subgroups. If $H$ is an $\Omega$-subgroup of $G$, then every $\Omega$-subgroup of $H$ is also an $\Omega$-subgroup of $G$, hence $H$ also satisfies ACC and DCC on *its* $\Omega$-subgroups, and therefore $H$ has an $\Omega$-composition series.

---

One is tempted to try to try do this explicitly by taking an $\Omega$-composition series of $G$,
$$1=N_0\triangleleft N_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft N_m=G$$
and trying to use it to obtain an $\Omega$-composition series for $H$, perhaps by intersecting the series with $H$,
$$1 = N_0\cap H \triangleleft N_1\cap H\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft N_m\cap H = H.$$
The problem is that while this is indeed a series of $\Omega$-subgroups that are normal in $H$, in general we won't get that the successive quotients $(N_{i+1}\cap H)/(N_i\cap H)$ is $\Omega$-simple. For example, taking $\Omega$ empty, so that we are talking about regular composition series, take a proper subgroup of $A_5$. The only composition series for $A_n$ is $1\triangleleft A_n$, since $A_n$ is simple, so that would yield the normal series $1\triangleleft H$; but this will not be a composition series for $H$ unless $H$ is cyclic of prime order or trivial. So you would need to start mucking about with $H$ itself. In the finite group case we obtain the result by induction on the order, but for arbitrary groups, as expected in this exercise and in Robinson's  book in general, I think you really need to go through 3.1.5. Which, by the way, should also deal with the second part of the exercise, dealing with $\Omega$-quotients.

Comment: Thank you (+1). This helps, although it seems like you have indeed proven that $H$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, but what about a composition series?

Comment: @Shaun: Not sure I understand your question: a composition series is what you get when $\Omega$ is empty, in which case "$\Omega$-subgroup" just means "subgroup", and "max-$\Omega$" and "min-$\Omega$" just mean "ACC and DCC on subgroups".

Comment: Ah, okay. I think I get it now. Thank you. I'm sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: What do you think of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4747801/104041), @ArturoMagidin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proposition is false as stated.  For a counterexample, consider a simple group that contains an element of infinite order  ($PSL(2,\mathbb{Q})$ will do).  It trivially has a composition series, but it also has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, which does not.

If you restrict the proposition to $\Omega$-subnormal subgroups, then it is true by a straightforward application of the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you. Let me think about it before accepting though . . .