# If $S$ is all finitary permutations of $\Bbb N$ and $A$ is the alternating subgroup, prove $1\lhd A\lhd S$ is the only composition series of $S$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, infinite-groups

This is **Exercise 3.2.2** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsymmetric-groups%5D+composition+series+), it is new to MSE.

Previous exercises of mine from the book include:

- [Abelian and nonabelian groups with the same composition factors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138096/104041)
- [If $G$ has an $\Omega$-composition series, prove that every $\Omega$-subgroup [of $G$ has] a composition series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141261/104041)

### The Details:

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

On page 16, *ibid.*, slightly paraphrased,

> If $1$ and $G$ are the only normal subgroups of $G$ and $G\neq 1$, then the group $G$ is said to be *simple*.

On page 28, *ibid.*,

> A *right operator group* is a triple $(G, \Omega, \alpha)$ consisting of a group $G$, a set $\Omega$ called the *operator domain* and a function $\alpha:G\times \Omega\to G$ such that $g\mapsto (g,\omega)\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $G$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. We shall write $g^\omega$ for $(g,\omega)\alpha$ and speak of the *$\Omega$-group* if the function $\alpha$ is understood.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $G$ is an $\Omega$-group, an *$\Omega$-subgroup* of $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is *$\Omega$-admissible*, that is, such that $h^\omega\in H$ whenever $h\in H$ and $\omega\in\Omega$.

On page 63, *ibid.*,

> Let $G$ be an operator group with operator domain $\Omega$. An $\Omega$-series (of finite length) in $G$ is a finite sequence of $\Omega$-subgroups including $1$ and $G$ such that each member of the sequence is a normal subgroup of its successor: thus a series can be written
>
> $$1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\dots\lhd G_l=G.$$
>
> The [. . .] quotient groups $G_{i+1}/G_i$ are the *factors* of the series.

On page 64, *ibid.*,

> If $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{T}$  are $\Omega$-series of [an $\Omega$-group] $G$, call $\mathbf{S}$ a *refinement* of $\mathbf{T}$ if every term of $\mathbf{T}$ is also a term of $\mathbf{S}$. If there is at least one term of $\mathbf{S}$ which is not a term of $\mathbf{T}$, then $\mathbf{S}$ is a *proper refinement* of $\mathbf{T}$.

On page 65, *ibid.*,

> An $\Omega$-series which has no proper refinements is called an *$\Omega$-composition series*.
>
> [. . .]
>
> If $\Omega$ is empty, we speak of a *composition series*.

### The Question:

> If $S$ is the group of all finitary permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $A$ is the alternating subgroup, prove that $1\lhd A\lhd S$ is the only composition series of $S$.

### Thoughts:

That

$$1\lhd A\lhd S\tag{1}$$

is a series for $S$ - not yet necessarily a composition series - is somewhat evident in the fact that $[S:A]=2$ (which I recognise is something I need to prove), meaning $A\lhd S$ (and, perhaps, the index prohibits any $H$ such that $A\lhd H\lhd S$), and $1$ is normal in each group. I don't yet know how to prove that $(1)$ is a composition series, let alone the only such series.

Perhaps the theorem below might help:

> **Theorem 3.2.1**: (Jordan) The alternating group $A_n$ is simple if and only if $n\neq 1,2$, or $4$.

However, strange things happen with infinite groups, so I'm not sure it applies to $A$.

One approach I have in mind to show that $(1)$ is unique is to suppose, for a contradiction, that another, distinct composition series

$$1=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd \dots\lhd G_l=S\tag{2}$$

exists for $S$. I'm not sure where to go from here though. I don't think mentioning this is at all productive but, nonetheless, it's a start . . .

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is a very natural embedding of $S_n$ into $S$. Actually, with this embedding we have $S=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty S_n$. Similarly, $A=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Now it is easy to show that $A$ is a simple group. Indeed, let $\{e\}\ne N\trianglelefteq A$. Then for some $n_0\geq 5$ we have $N\cap A_{n_0}\ne\{e\}$. It follows that $N\cap A_{n}\ne\{e\}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. And since $A_n$ is a simple group for all $n\geq n_0$, it follows that $N\cap A_n=A_n$ for all such $n$. Hence:

$$\begin{align}
N\cap A &=N\cap\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)\\
&=N\cap\left(\bigcup\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty A_n\right)\\
&=\bigcup\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty(N\cap A_n)\\
&=\bigcup\limits_{n=n_0}^\infty A_n\\
&=A.
\end{align}$$

And so $A=N$ in that case. $A$ is indeed a simple group.

The next step is showing that the only normal subgroups of $S$ are the $S,A,\{e\}$. So suppose $S\ne N\trianglelefteq S$. Then $N\cap A\trianglelefteq A$, and so $N\cap A=A$ or $N\cap A=\{e\}$. In the first case we get $A=N$, since $A$ is clearly a maximal subgroup of $S$. (it clearly has index $2$). The case $N\cap A=\{e\}$ is a bit more interesting. We have to show that $N=\{e\}$ in that case. Assume otherwise. Note that $N$ can't have exactly two elements, because then it would be contained in the center of $S$, but it is easy to check that $S$ has trivial center. (same proof as for $S_n$). So $|N|\geq 3$, and so it has some nontrivial permutations $\sigma,\tau\in N$. Since $N\cap A=\{e\}$ it follows that $\sigma, \tau$ are both odd. But note that at least one of the elements $\sigma^2, \sigma\tau$ is an even permutation which is not the identity. So $N$ contains a nontrivial even permutation, a contradiction.

Ok, so now your problem is pretty much solved, because you know all the normal subgroups of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove it's a composition series, you need to prove that $A$ is  simple. Let $1 \ne N \unlhd A$ and let $1 \ne x \in N$.

We want to prove that $N=A$. So let $y \in A$ and we will  prove that $y \in N$. Let $X$ be a finite subset of ${\mathbb N}$ that contains the supports of both $x$ and $y$, and choose $X$ such that $|X| \ge 5$. Then $x \in N \cap A_X$ (the alternating group on the set $X$).

Since $|X| \ge 5$, $A_X$ is simple, and $N \cap A_X \unlhd A_X$, so $N \cap A_X = A_X$. But $y \in A_X$, so  $y \in N$ and we have proved that $N=A$ and that $A$ is simple.

To prove it is the unique composition series let $1 \lhd N \cdots \lhd S$ be another one, with $N$ simple. If $N=A$ then we have the same series. Otherwise, since $N$ and $A$ are simple, we have $A \cap N = 1$. Since $|S:A|=2$, we must have $|N| = 2$, so $S = A \times N$, and $N \le Z(S)$.

I will leave you to prove that that cannot happen.